# MySQL INSERT on SELECT Deadlock multiplayer game

Tags: mysql, database, deadlock, database-deadlocks

- MySQL version: 5.7
- Storage engine: InnoDB
- To put you in situation this is a card game (in nodejs). In this case a 9 player table-game. And each player can play in a 4 table-games simultaniously.

Recently i'm facing to a recurrent Deadlocks, like 1 to 5 per minute on a 1K concurrent users. The query below is called an average of 2 times per minute and per user.

- The user wants to play.
- The server ALWAYS finds the 1st empty spot(seat) in the 1st available table-game.

I don't know how to solve that since this query is built to handle possible race conditions when 2+ different players (or same player 2+ times) execute the Insert query.

Of course, I can handle race conditions by unique keys but is unmanageable on a peak of 100+ users searching for a free spot. Provably it will cause 91+ rejections by dupplicate key.

---

```
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------

*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 100539324, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 5, locked 5
LOCK WAIT 23 lock struct(s), heap size 3520, 111 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 6782, OS thread handle 2460, query id 138188765 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Creating sort index
INSERT INTO app_tables_players (user_id, game_id, seat_number, username, state, folded) SELECT 597, a.id, b.id AS seat_number, 'some_username', 'temp', false FROM (SELECT id FROM app_tables_games WHERE table_id = 6 AND seats_total > seats_taken AND id NOT IN (SELECT game_id FROM app_users_state WHERE user_id = 597)) AS a, `app_temp_players_9` AS b WHERE b.id NOT IN (SELECT seat_number FROM app_tables_players WHERE game_id = a.id) ORDER BY a.id ASC LIMIT 1

*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 75 page no 51 n bits 1120 index seat_number_game_id of table `nodejs`.`app_tables_players` trx id 100539324 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting
Record lock, heap no 964 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d8f6; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b437b; asc  kC{;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 100539325, ACTIVE 0 sec setting auto-inc lock, thread declared inside InnoDB 4743
mysql tables in use 5, locked 5
22 lock struct(s), heap size 3520, 151 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 6702, OS thread handle 11428, query id 138188764 localhost 127.0.0.1 root Creating sort index
INSERT INTO app_tables_players (user_id, game_id, seat_number, username, state, folded) SELECT 613, a.id, b.id AS seat_number, 'some_username2', 'tmp', false FROM (SELECT id FROM app_tables_games WHERE table_id = 14 AND seats_total > seats_taken AND id NOT IN (SELECT game_id FROM app_users_state WHERE user_id = 613)) AS a, `app_temp_players_9` AS b WHERE b.id NOT IN (SELECT seat_number FROM app_tables_players WHERE game_id = a.id) ORDER BY a.id ASC LIMIT 1

*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 75 page no 51 n bits 1120 index seat_number_game_id of table `nodejs`.`app_tables_players` trx id 100539325 lock mode S locks gap before rec
Record lock, heap no 18 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 06; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d6e4; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b5a47; asc  kZG;;

Record lock, heap no 97 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d97e; asc    ~;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b5d1e; asc  k] ;;

Record lock, heap no 160 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 05; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d93e; asc    >;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b4cb3; asc  kL ;;

Record lock, heap no 181 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d92f; asc    /;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b5c0b; asc  k\ ;;

Record lock, heap no 267 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d9b2; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b5b9a; asc  k[ ;;

Record lock, heap no 272 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 05; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d999; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b5d43; asc  k]C;;

Record lock, heap no 307 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008da33; asc    3;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b6182; asc  ka ;;

Record lock, heap no 346 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008da38; asc    8;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b5fbd; asc  k_ ;;

Record lock, heap no 530 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 05; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d9b2; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b544e; asc  kTN;;

Record lock, heap no 556 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 05; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d97e; asc    ~;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b62f3; asc  kb ;;

Record lock, heap no 629 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d999; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b5f41; asc  k_A;;

Record lock, heap no 804 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 05; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008da33; asc    3;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b60bc; asc  k` ;;

Record lock, heap no 906 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d93e; asc    >;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b4988; asc  kI ;;

Record lock, heap no 962 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d928; asc    (;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b5b03; asc  k[ ;;

Record lock, heap no 964 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 3; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 1; hex 04; asc  ;;
 1: len 4; hex 0008d8f6; asc     ;;
 2: len 4; hex 006b437b; asc  kC{;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
TABLE LOCK table `nodejs`.`app_tables_players` trx id 100539325 lock mode AUTO-INC waiting
*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (2)
```

---

Query causing the problem:

```
INSERT INTO app_tables_players
    (user_id, 
    game_id, 
    seat_number) 
SELECT
    597, 
    a.id, 
    b.id AS seat_number
FROM 
    (SELECT id 
    FROM
        app_tables_games 
    WHERE
        table_id = 14
        AND seats_total > seats_taken 
        AND id NOT IN (
            SELECT game_id 
            FROM   app_users_state 
            WHERE  user_id = 597
        )
    ) AS a, 
    app_temp_players_9 AS b 
WHERE
    b.id NOT IN (
        SELECT seat_number 
        FROM   app_tables_players 
        WHERE  game_id = a.id
    ) 
ORDER BY a.id ASC 
LIMIT 1;
```

---

- Explain query:

`id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra`

`1, INSERT, app_tables_players, , ALL, , , , , , ,`

`1, PRIMARY, app_tables_games, , ref, table_id,table_id_seats_taken_seats_total, table_id_seats_taken_seats_total, 4, const, 24, 33.33, Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort`

`1, PRIMARY, b, , index, , id, 1, , 9, 100.00, Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)`

`4, DEPENDENT SUBQUERY, app_tables_players, , index_subquery, seat_number_game_id,game_id_user_id,game_id,seat_number,game_id_state, seat_number_game_id, 6, func,func, 2, 100.00, Using where; Using index`

`3, SUBQUERY, app_users_state, , ref, game_id_user_id,user_id,game_id, user_id, 4, const, 4, 100.00,`

- Fiddle:
  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe63f7

NOTE: Sometimes the Deadlock occurs with the query above and:

```
DELETE FROM app_users_states WHERE game_id = some_id AND user_id = some_id
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some more research about all the deadlocks faced in this application i saw that there was 2-3 different types or situations.

One of them was a `lock mode AUTO-INC waiting`

So, 1st transaction have the autoincrement `id` column locked and waiting for index 'X' and 2nd transaction have a lock on index 'X' and waiting for the AUTO-INC lock.

Since i need the `id` column to get the `lastInsertId` and use it later in a `SELECT`, there was a MUST to have this autoincrement column. To solve that i created a known `UUID` value in my application and stored as binary(16) instead of autoincrement int`id`.

Second and thid problem was related to `INSERT` on `SELECT` in different or the same table in the same query. Like (siple example);

`INSERT INTO tableA some_colX (SELECT some_colY FROM tableA WHERE some_colZ = 1 LIMIT 1)`

This `SELECT`s used a `lock mode S locks gap before rec` but the `INSERT` requires a `lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting`. In my `INSERT` i was doing `SELECT`s in 3 different tables and in other part of the application there was some others `UPDATE`s or others `INSERT`s, so lots of deadlocks everywhere.

To solve part of that i changed (some of) the `SELECT`s inside de `INSERT` statement adding `FOR UPDATE` since this, sets a `IX lock` instead of `S lock`, preventing that other query get first the `X lock in this record/gap`

I realised later, that there was another deadlock in my application. What you think? Another different (and the latest) `INSERT` on `SELECT` query in other completly different tables.

From 1 to 5 deadlocks per minute to 1 deadlock per.. 10 minutes or more.

So, as my personal opinion (use case), dont use `INSERT` and `SELECT` in the same query. Use procedures, transactions... And check if the `SELECT`s are using the properly Indexes.

Sorry for my English :)

Good luck.

*UPDATE:*

Chganged 1 Index in the main table involved into de `INSERT` and 1 Index on one of the `SELECT` tables. Result: by now, 0 deadlocks in 2 hours